# Clean symfony 7 demo app hangs with max execution exceded

Tags: php, symfony

I run macos 13 (ventura), php 8.2 installed with homebrew.
I have Symfony CLI version 5.7.8 installed

When I create a new project (also tried the --demo parametetr):
`symfony new my_project_directory --version="7.0.*" --webapp`

When I start the server: `symfony server:start` and go to the url, the page is displayed but the debug bar keeps on loading with "Loading the web debug toolbar… Attempt #27".

At some point it all stops and xdebug reports: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /Users/xxxx/Sites/local.covercoll.com/www/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Caster/ClassStub.php on line 53`.

I've followed all steps according the getting started guide, but get stuck pretty muck directly starting up the app.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/getting_started/index.html

Is there anything I have missed?? What things can I check? I've repeated the process a few times, every time the same problem.

Comment: Try to increase the max_execution_time in php.ini file to 300 or 500 and restart your web server

Comment: The server is the one Synfony spins up itself when I start the server in the command line: `symfony server:start`

I feel increasing the execution time wont solve the problem, only gives the problem more time as this should just work out of the box, and I am very interested in the cause of this.